# How do I get source to a snap package?

Tags: snap

In apt, I'm able to run `apt source PACKAGE_NAME` to get the source to a package.

I'm trying to do the same thing in snap.  I can run `snap info PACKAGE_NAME |grep ^contact:` and try to figure out where the source is manually.  Is there something better?  Something that will download the source for me?  (and potentially build it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snap packages are not the same as debs, and do not have "source" packages. They are also generally meant to include all their dependencies, rather than relying on package dependencies to provide them.

You can however, browse the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store) to find apps, and in the app details page, the *Developer website* link *may* point to a repository containing the `snapcraft.yaml` file from which the snap was built.